# Sampling records from MongoDB database allowing duplicates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to get some random records from my small MongoDB database but I want to sometimes see duplicates.

Sample function doesn't really work for me because it might create duplicates only with specific conditions my query and database won't meet.

Is there any reasonable way of getting some random records while allowing duplicates without downloading entire collection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910751/random-sort-order

Comment: @D.SM That thread isn't helpful in this case as it either uses $sample or uses methods that still are unable to generate duplicates

Comment: Those are only options.