# random results in mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

good afternoon,

I'm not able to do the "select" in php for MongoDB.

I need 20 random results. I'm trying to use the rand () function, but I can not make it work.

I'm trying this:

```
 return $db->anuncios->find()->rand()->limit(20);
```

But is not working.

Comment: This has been disussed about 10 times if you search google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb as a brief example. One thing, I would recommend not using `skip` if you can.