# How to find random records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want find many random records doing only 1 query.

I tried:

```
var count = db.collections.count()
var rand = function(){return Math.floor( Math.random() * count )}

db.collection.find().limit(-1).skip(rand()).next();
```

But this returns only one document. I need to get more random records.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have written a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-random-docs
that fix duplication issues and return only unique random docs

    npm i unique-random-docs

feel free to check it out!

Answer (score 14):

Another way to achive

```
db.Colletion.find().limit( 50 ).skip( _rand() * db.Collection.count() )
```

change the limit() as per your requirement, Hope this will Help....

Thanks

Comment: This too inefficient. Getting all records first, then offsetting cannot be the right way for this...

Comment: This is fine, but if I want a PHP code to get the random records out of 100 records and display how that would look like?

Comment: `db.COLLECTION.find().limit( 1 ).skip(_rand() * db.COLLECTION.count())` – awesome for me, thanks!

Comment: @danielrvt, you're wrong since MongoDB uses cursors, this will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Pass a function that returns a `Boolean` value in the `find` parameter:

```
db.collection.find(function () {return Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))})
```

You can see how many records were returned using `count()`:

```
db.collection.find(...).count()
```

Also, if you want to limit the document cout use `limit()`:

```
db.collection.find(...).limit(/* how many? */)
```

Comment: Of course the speed of such a thing means you should never do this

Comment: @Sammaye I know it's not optimal, but for Mongo shell it's enough.

Comment: please give me code for PHP

Comment: When using `limit`, this is going to strongly favor docs near the beginning of the collection.