# PHP Runtime Performance Debugging

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have a simple PHP script that makes some updates to a Mongo database:

```
$properties = db()->properties->find([], ['_id' => true]);
foreach($properties as $property) {
  db()->properties->update(
    ['_id' => $property['_id']],
    ['$set' => ['random' => [lcg_value(), lcg_value()]]],
    ['w' => 0]
  );
}
```

I am basically assigning a random point to each record in the "properties" collection as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9499484/120067) for querying random records. This script runs on my local system in about a minute and a half for the dataset I am operating on (about 200,000 documents).

I considered using JavaScript and running the update server-side, but running server-side code from a driver requires special permissions that are too permissive. I dislike the fact that I have to pull down all that data and send an update for each record but I couldn't figure out a way to do it in Mongo as a batch operation.

Regardless of the excessive network traffic it is fairly quick since I am only pulling down the ID and my write back to the database doesn't have the write consistency enabled.

When running this on the production machine the script suddenly takes MUCH longer. I killed the job after about 30 minutes. The production site uses a custom compiled PHP installation for various other reasons. I assume the custom compiling is the reason but I am unsure how to go about tracking down the exact reason for the slowdown.

My thoughts so far:

- Maybe some optimization module is not enabled on the production machine that is enabled on my machine? I assume something like the opcache wouldn't impact this since we are executing a CLI script once, not making a bunch of requests to the same script.
- Maybe some compile time option that makes gcc produce a more optimized binary?
- Or perhaps the Mongo module is communicating slower because of it is missing some faster networking library and has to fall back to a slower one?

The custom compiled PHP is compile with the following options and modules:

```
./configure --enable-static --enable-cli --disable-all --with-curl \
  --enable-mongo --enable-json --enable-hash --enable-libxml \
  --enable-simplexml --enable-filter --enable-dom --enable-ftp \
  --enable-pcntl --enable-posix --enable-xmlwriter
```

If I do a diff between my local systems modules and this custom compiled version I get the following modules that are on my local system but not the production machine:

```
bz2
calendar
ctype
exif
fileinfo
gettext
iconv
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
session
shmop
sockets
sqlite3
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xsl
zip
zlib
```

None of those look like they would impact performance.

Comparing versions you can see I am running similar versions. The custom version:

```
PHP 5.5.13 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2014 17:00:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

My local machine:

```
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: May  3 2014 07:09:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
  with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

I am assuming the slowness is due to IO and not CPU since the script is mostly about communicating the the Mongo database. It does calculate a random number but that doesn't factor in since my custom compiled PHP actually generates the random number much faster. Generating a million random numbers using lcg_value on my local php:

```
real 0m0.420s
user 0m0.411s
sys  0m0.008s
```

But with my custom compiled PHP:

```
real 0m0.081s
user 0m0.076s
sys  0m0.005s
```

The problem is not due to the network or CPU capabilities of the production environment. I ran the custom compiled PHP binary on my local machine and it was significantly slower there as well. So I'm pretty sure it is something to do with how it is compiled, modules used or configuration.

Anybody with any ideas of where to look next?

Comment: Tell us about the disk drive and what else is running on the prod system. Is anything else running at the same time? Is it being used for anything else?  What else is different between prod and your test/dev machine?

Comment: Have you profiled your code at all to get a better understanding as to where you are spending your time?  I would think that would be the next logical step.

Comment: @AlisterBulman - It's nothing with the production system. Note my last paragraph. If I use the same PHP binary on my local system (instead of the system-wide PHP) it also ran slow. So the custom PHP runs slow on both my system and the server. My local system-wide binary doesn't run slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mike-brant pointed me in the right direction.

I added the Xdebug module to the custom compiled PHP binary. Ran the script with the custom binary vs my local system binary. The custom binary spent most of it's time in the update function. The update should be very quick since the write concern is set to 0. In my local system the update only accounts for 10% of the runtime. But with the custom PHP its' 97%.

This makes me think the issue is some difference between the Mongo driver. The custom binary is using 1.5.3 and my local system is 1.4.4.

I'm going to investigate this further (possibly on a different StackOverflow question). But my immediate question of how to go about pin-pointing where to look was answered by @mike-brant.

Comment: Further update for anybody interested. This QA narrowed it down to update. A bit of research shows that as of 1.5 Mongo no longer supports fire and forget meaning it was waiting for the reply even though I set the write concern to 0. Using the batch update API allowed me to rewrite my script to be fast again. See [this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24433878/120067) for the debugging of update.