# Mongo Update Speed

Tags: php, performance, mongodb

I have a script that when run on my local system runs quickly but when running on the production system it runs much slower. I have confirmed with a PHP profiler that the slow-down is happening in the update method on the MongoCollection object. I have copied the PHP software (binary and modules) from the production system to my local system to make sure it isn't due to a difference in machine/network. Running the production PHP software on my local system also runs slow. So the problem is not machine or network. Since it is the same script it is also not something with my script. This points to one of three possibilities:

- Difference in PHP version
- Difference in Mongo driver version
- Difference in configuration

The script in question iterates through all records in the collection and makes an update for each one. The update has the write concern set to 0 as speed is more important than knowing it was executed successfully. The PHP profiler stopped providing information once it called update (since update is implemented in C). So I turned next to strace to see if the system calls could help explain the difference in speed. The loop where the updates are being issued has the following strace output on the fast system:

```
sendto(3, "\202\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\321\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 130, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 130
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
sendto(3, "\202\0\0\0\207\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\321\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 130, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 130
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
sendto(3, "\202\0\0\0\210\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\321\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 130, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 130
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
```

I am outputting "." between each update so I have feedback to indicate how fast the updates are going. When running the same script on the slower PHP I see the following:

```
sendto(3, "\357\0\0\0v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 239, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 239
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 30000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "1\0\0\0009\0.\nv\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 49
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
sendto(3, "\357\0\0\0w\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 239, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 239
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 30000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "1\0\0\0\201\0.\nw\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 49
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
sendto(3, "\357\0\0\0x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 239, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 239
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 30000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "1\0\0\0\320\0.\nx\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 49
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
sendto(3, "\357\0\0\0y\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0properties_2"..., 239, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 239
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 30000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "1\0\0\0\365\0.\ny\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 49
write(1, ".", 1)                        = 1
```

Notice that we have added system calls. It looks like it is checking the reply which to me indicates it's not using write concern 0. The major difference between the two PHP installations is the fast one is using driver 1.4.5 while the slow one is using 1.5.3.

I compared the update code for both versions. In 1.4.5 [it seems to just send the message and return](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/1.4.5/collection.c#L957). On the other hand looking at 1.5.3 [it sends the message then gets a reply](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/collection.c#L1017). I don't see anything about skipping checking the reply if the write condition is 0. If you follow the code that extracts the reply you can see where it eventually calls these two additional system calls.

Can someone who understand this better help me figure out how to get my code running fast in production. On the fast PHP install (mongo driver 1.4.5) the script executes in just 2-3 minutes. On the slow system (mongo driver 1.5.3) I killed it after 30 minutes because I was tired of waiting. Who knows how long it would have taken to get fully done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Note**: updated original answer after some extra research)

The new [write operation commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/#write-method-acknowledgements) which came in with 2.6 and hence are in use between any supported driver (PHP 1.5+) and MongoDB server (2.6+) mean that the new semantics of `w=0` writes are in play.  That means that the server waits for the operation to complete before sending a response (that is, the only difference between `w=0` and `w=1` is that `w=0` omits the error details).  The driver still waits for that response before returning from the call (i.e. is no longer fire and forget).

You can see this in the MongoDB shell itself also, and the official way around it is to use the new [Bulk API](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/84922794768/mongodbs-new-bulk-api).  Although I know the 1.5 driver will fall back to legacy write operations when connecting to a 2.4 and below server, there is no way to force that behavior in the PHP driver.

Comment: My code is explicitly setting ['w' => 0] on each update. On 1.4 it seems to work. On 1.5 it seems to be waiting for a reply.

Comment: You're right, and since it changed the answer completely, I re-wrote it

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sad to see that Mongo dropped fire and forget. I can see why it shouldn't be the default but it's useful in cases where performance is more important than reliability. You mentioned the console does this also, but I rewrote my script in JavaScript and it executes quickly (same general speed as the 1.4 driver).

Is the Bulk API available from PHP or do we have to use JavaScript in the console?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The batch API allowed me to get my script running again in around 2.5 minutes instead of 30+ minutes.

Comment: Sad. Did not find any word about changes http://php.net/manual/ru/mongo.writeconcerns.php. Killed an hour on the issue, until found this post. +1