# Mongodb random sample selection but unique and different every time I ask for a new sample

Tags: mongodb, random, statistics, analytics

I have Mongo Database, and I want to select a random sample of users, which I found a solution for in different places (including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb)).

Now, the hard part: How to get a unique and random set of users every time I make a request to mongo that doesn't correlate to the random sample I received in the (at least) last  request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to store the used up samples in an array and do your random query with the addition of the not-in-array-elements condition `$nin`. Below is sample code for demonstrating `$nin`, which you can edit and play around with on my  [Saturn Fiddle](https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/new-random-sample-every-time).

```
// Welcome to SaturnAPI!
// Start collaborating with MongoDB fiddles and accomplish more.
// Start your code below these comments.

// Create a new collection
var Posts = new Mongo.Collection(null);

//Insert some data
Posts.insert({
  number: 1,
  author: "Saturn Sam", 
  message: "Hello!"
});
Posts.insert({
  number: 2,
  author: "Saturn Sam2", 
  message: "Hello!"
});
Posts.insert({
  number: 3,
  author: "Saturn Sam3", 
  message: "Hello!"
});

// Returns all records
// Posts.find({}).fetch()

// Returns all records with `number` not equal to `2` or `1`
Posts.find({number: {$nin: [2, 1]}}).fetch()
```

Comment: If I know which users numbers to exclude, then this is not random :)  In my case users numbers to exclude is unknown, and those number is randomly generated

Comment: In each query, you want a random set that has not been chosen in previous queries, right

Comment: Oh, now I get you. Yes your solutions is correct and doable, but I'm trying to find a more native mongo solution. Appreciated!

Comment: That's going to be tough, since you need some memory of previous queries.

Comment: If no other solution that's natively done by the Mongodb, then, your solution is the solution, or at least a seed for a solution. I will wait for a while for other answers, if not, I'll have your answer checked!