# How do we find random sample of data in rmongodb?

Tags: r, mongodb, sample, random, rmongodb

I have 200GB of data in my mongo database. I have connected it to R using rmongodb.Now I want to put 1000 random records from the database into a dataframe for analyzing. How do I do that?

I want to query in R, not in MongoDb. Also, I dont want a single record, but a 1000 records.

Comment: Also check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb

Comment: It might be worth noting here that the next release ( and current development branch ) of MongoDB has a `$sample` aggregation pipeline stage that does exactly this, without the required testing of other current solutions and also allows for other stages to manipulate and/or filter the data before that "sample" is taken. Food for thought.

Comment: The post that is mentioned works on MongoDb. But I want to query in R

Comment: @stkusr1234: then why do you tag it with [tag:mongodb]?

Comment: That is because my data is in monogodb.