# Sails JS: Select random records from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm newbie of Sails JS framwork and I'm trying to write a small quiz app. Each quiz, my app will select 6 random questions from question collection.

Is it possible in SailsJS 0.11, MongoDB 3.6.8?
How can I do that?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `find` method with `skip` and `limit` criteria.

```
Question
  .count()
  .then(count => Question.find().limit(6).skip(parseInt(Math.random() * count)))
  .then(questions => questions.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()))
  .then(questions => doSomethingWith(questions))
  .catch(sails.log.error);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. Is your solution return 6 questions next to each other? Like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and return 3 4 5 6 7 8. I need something like: 1 3 5 6 7 9

Comment: You can apply `sort` method on array though and randomize it. I will update answer in few mins.