# MongoDB $sample is slow

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 4.4.3 to query a random record from a collection :

```js
db.MyCollection.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }])
```

This query takes 20s (when a `find` query takes 0.2s)

[Mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) states :

> If all the following conditions are met, $sample uses a pseudo-random cursor to select documents:
>
> - $sample is the first stage of the pipeline
> - N is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection
> - The collection contains more than 100 documents

Here

- `$sample` is the only stage of the pipeline
- N = 1
- `MyCollection` contains 46 millions documents

This problem is similar to [MongoDB Aggregation with $sample very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679999/mongodb-aggregation-with-sample-very-slow), which does not provide an answer for Mongo4.4.3

So why is this query so slow ?

### Details

#### Query Planner

```js
db.MyCollection.aggregate([{$sample: {size: 1}}]).explain()
{
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "DATABASE.MyCollection",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "MULTI_ITERATOR"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sampleFromRandomCursor" : {
                "size" : 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongodb4-3",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.3",
        "gitVersion" : "913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1611128334, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"ZDxiOTnmG/zLKNtDIAWhxmjHHLM="),
            "keyId" : 6915708270745223171
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1611128334, 1)
}
```

#### Execution stats

[image: Execution stats]

Comment: What are the explain plans?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Aggregation with $sample very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679999/mongodb-aggregation-with-sample-very-slow)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I updated the question with the explain plans, is it what you wanted ?

Comment: @AlexBlex No unfortunately, the accepted answer refers to a prior version of MongoDB, and the most voted one doesn't provide a solution

Comment: @cadoman It does not provide a solution, but it answers the question. Not all problems can be solved in SO format, some require escalation to software vendors.