# Mongoose random object from a long list

Tags: performance, mongoose, lodash

As Mongoose doesn't have an option for random find, which of the following is better to use? (less resource consuming)

Minimal query and then big query:

```
Page.find()
    .select('_id')
    .then(function(pages){
        var randomPage = _.sample(pages);
        Page.findOne({id: randomPage._id})
        .populate('comments')
        .then(function(page){...}
    }
```

One query and picking a random item:

```
Page.find()
    .populate('comments')
    .then(function(pages){
        var randomPage = _.sample(pages);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random record from MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way is to use `$sample` operator in aggregation pipeline, which allowed since mongodb v3.2

DOCS: [$sample (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)