# Mongodb 3.0 equivalent to $sample

Tags: mongodb

I can't find online hosting for Mongodb that supports v3.2 Unfortunately, this means I can't use `$sample`, which has the ability to randomly select `n` documents from a query:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Does anyone know an equivalent workaround in Mongo 3.0?

Comment: Not a simple/straightforward way, other than upgrading to 3.2 :-)

Comment: Plenty of options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb