# Select random document with filter with pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I [found, that to select random document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33578506/258483), I need to use `$sample` command:

```
// Get one random document from the mycoll collection.
db.mycoll.aggregate(
   { $sample: { size: 1 } }
)
```

but what if I need to filter documents and THEN take random one?

I am processing documents, which are not processed yet with

```
query = {'start_time': {'$exists': False}}
hp_entries = mongo.hyperparameters_collection.find(query)
```

How would I do with random?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As any other aggregation stage it takes input from the previous stage.

Prepend the `$sample` with [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter the documents. E.g.:

```
db.hyperparameters_collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "start_time": { "$exists": False } } },
    { "$sample": { "size": 1 } }
])
```