# MongoDB - return X number of random records

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my node.js server, I am trying to return 4 random records from my collection.

Here is my current code, the issue is that currently it returns between 0-4 random records from my collection, whereas I want to return 4 (no more no less) random records every time.

```
db.collection('articles')
.find()
.limit( 4 )
.skip(Math.round(Math.random() * 4))
.sort("date", -1).toArray()
```

Any help or advice is appreciate - thank you in advance!

> I had a look at some similar questions but they all only seem to
>   generate random records between 0-X records, not a set amount.

Comment: Maybe [`slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)?

Comment: hmmm interesting, cheers man - and feel free to try answer haha! @RishatMuhametshin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random record from MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb)

Comment: Use `$sample` aggregation pipeline operator

Comment: @danjones_mcr I updated my answer, maybe it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) aggregation pipeline for that.

> Randomly selects the specified number of documents from its input.
>
> The `$sample` stage has the following syntax:
>
> `{ $sample: { size: <positive integer> } }`

E.g. this code returns 4 random documents:

```
db.collection('articles').aggregate([
   { $sample: { size: 4 } }
]);
```

If you need to select `x` random  documents by some criterias, then just add [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)