# C# MongoDB - FindOne random record

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine

How to get 1 random record from MongoDB with FindOne method in C# ? Please show me example.
I Made something like that:

var randomN = _randomNicknames.Find(Query.Null).SetSkip(randomValue).SetLimit(1);

But I get collection of elements but not 1 element.

Comment: Copy [the answer using `$sample`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33578506/2313887) and not the top scored answer. Despite the votes, it's wrong.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Thank you!